# Calling Javascript Function from swift - Function Not recognized

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I am building a SWIFT app which calls javascript functions from an external file-jssource,js. I followed this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/javascriptcore-swift/ for the same,  but the function (func helloWorld and func jsDemo1) is returning undefined for the print statements. Both these functions exists in the jsource.js file. I am not sure why my code is unable to call the functions in the file.

This is the code I have untill now.

```swift
import JavaScriptCore
 
class CheckIn{
   public let context = JSContext()

func initializeJS() {
    
    
    
    let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
    
    // Specify the path to the jssource.js file.
    if let jsSourcePath = bundle.path(forResource: "jssource", ofType: "js") {
        do {
            // Load its contents to a String variable.
            let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)

            // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
            context?.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}

func jsDemo1() {
    let firstname = "Mickey"
    let lastname = "Mouse"
 
    if let functionFullname = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("getFullname") {
        // Call the function that composes the fullname.
        if let fullname = functionFullname.call(withArguments: [firstname, lastname]) {
            print(fullname.toString())
        }
    }
}
    

func helloWorld() {
    let variableHelloWorld = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("helloWorld")
    print(variableHelloWorld?.toString())
    
}
}
```

Comment: The first block of code is wrapped in a `if` check, to see if it can find the file, is this first bit running? `if let jsSourcePath ... {}`, put an `else` clause and print a message to console to see if its failing to find the file first of all. (it would make sense for `initializeJS` to return a Bool, to let the outside class know whether the setup succeeded or not)

Comment: You can also add an exception handler to the JSContext, in case theres something in the js file that can't be parsed

`jsContext.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
   print("JS Exception: \(exception?.toString())")
  }`

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin -  I have tried adding exception. But it doesn't throw any error. I have verified that the file is detected and the jsSourceContents is successfully assigned to the contents of the jssource.js file.

Comment: Edit your question and include the contents of your JS file